# Is it possible to create a custom vector type with performance similar to System.Numerics.Vector4?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

The `System.Numerics.Vector4` type has great performance because the CLR can optimize it to use vectorized CPU instructions. However, I would like to create my own custom 4-element, single-precision float vector type so that I can add various convenience methods and properties, attributes, interfaces, etc... (I.E., more than I can do with extension methods.) Unfortunately, my own vector type doesn't perform nearly as well as `System.Numerics.Vector4`, even if it uses a `System.Numerics.Vector4` internally. Is there any way to get `System.Numerics.Vector4`-like performance out of a custom vector type?

Here's a program that attempts (and mostly fails) to get improved performance by nesting a `System.Numerics.Vector4` inside a custom vector type:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Numerics;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

class Program
{
    private const int ARR_LENGTH = 1000;
    private const int OUTER_LOOP = 1000000;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        TestVector4();
        TestMyVector();
        TestMyVectorSimd();
    }

    static void TestVector4()
    {
        Vector4[] arr = new Vector4[ARR_LENGTH];
        for(int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
            arr[i] = new Vector4(i, i, i, i);

        Stopwatch sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        Vector4 total = default;
        for(int i = 0; i < OUTER_LOOP; i++)
        {
            total = default;
            for(int j = 0; j < ARR_LENGTH; j++)
                total += arr[j];
        }
        sw.Stop();

        Console.WriteLine($"System.Numerics.Vector4: {total}  ({sw.Elapsed})");
    }

    static void TestMyVector()
    {
        MyVector[] arr = new MyVector[ARR_LENGTH];
        for(int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
            arr[i] = new MyVector(i, i, i, i);

        Stopwatch sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        MyVector total = default;
        for(int i = 0; i < OUTER_LOOP; i++)
        {
            total = default;
            for(int j = 0; j < ARR_LENGTH; j++)
                total += arr[j];
        }
        sw.Stop();

        Console.WriteLine($"MyVector: {total}  ({sw.Elapsed})");
    }

    static void TestMyVectorSimd()
    {
        MyVectorSimd[] arr = new MyVectorSimd[ARR_LENGTH];
        for(int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
            arr[i] = new MyVectorSimd(i, i, i, i);

        Stopwatch sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        MyVectorSimd total = default;
        for(int i = 0; i < OUTER_LOOP; i++)
        {
            total = default;
            for(int j = 0; j < ARR_LENGTH; j++)
                total += arr[j];
        }
        sw.Stop();

        Console.WriteLine($"MyVectorSimd: {total}  ({sw.Elapsed})");
    }
}

struct MyVector
{
    public float X, Y, Z, W;

    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining | MethodImplOptions.AggressiveOptimization)]
    public MyVector(float x, float y, float z, float w)
    {
        X = x;
        Y = y;
        Z = z;
        W = w;
    }

    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining | MethodImplOptions.AggressiveOptimization)]
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"<{X}, {Y}, {Z}, {W}>";
    }

    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining | MethodImplOptions.AggressiveOptimization)]
    public static MyVector operator +(MyVector left, MyVector right)
    {
        left.X += right.X;
        left.Y += right.Y;
        left.Z += right.Z;
        left.W += right.W;
        return left;
    }
}

struct MyVectorSimd
{
    public Vector4 V;

    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining | MethodImplOptions.AggressiveOptimization)]
    public MyVectorSimd(float x, float y, float z, float w)
    {
        V = new Vector4(x, y, z, w);
    }

    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining | MethodImplOptions.AggressiveOptimization)]
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return V.ToString();
    }

    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining | MethodImplOptions.AggressiveOptimization)]
    public static MyVectorSimd operator +(MyVectorSimd left, MyVectorSimd right)
    {
        left.V += right.V;
        return left;
    }
}
```

This program has 3 tests in it. The first tests the performance of `System.Numerics.Vector4`. The second tests the performance of a custom vector type `MyVector` using simple element-by-element addition. And the third tests the performance of a custom vector type `MyVectorSimd` that itself uses a nested `System.Numerics.Vector4`. Here are the results on my computer running a Release build on .Net Core 3.1:

```
System.Numerics.Vector4: <499500, 499500, 499500, 499500>  (00:00:01.0635501)
MyVector: <499500, 499500, 499500, 499500>  (00:00:04.8566430)
MyVectorSimd: <499500, 499500, 499500, 499500>  (00:00:03.4586021)
```

As you can see, both of the custom vector types perform much worse than `System.Numerics.Vector4`, though the one that uses `System.Numerics.Vector4` internally is still a bit better than the one that doesn't.

So to reiterate my question, is there any way to get a custom vector type to perform as well as a `System.Numerics.Vector4`?

Comment: Just make sure that your copy type is inmutable (this is a standing advice for .NET structs) and you should be fine Just add readonly to the whole type. The optimisations should generally apply to all "inmutable structs of 4 floats".

Comment: Built-in `Vector4` uses some cpu intrinsics under the hood, as you can in [sources](https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/Vector4_Intrinsics.cs,3891837891678bcd) I guess that's the main reason of great performance. There is a good [article](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/using-net-hardware-intrinsics-api-to-accelerate-machine-learning-scenarios/) regarding this topic with examples

Comment: You may also check this API [proposal](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/23057), I guess you'll some answers here as well

Comment: @Christopher Making `MyVectorSimd` readonly does indeed improve performance to the level of `System.Numerics.Vector4`, thanks for the tip! However, I'd strongly prefer not to have to do that since `System.Numerics.Vector4` itself is not readonly and modifying individual members is something I do a lot.

Comment: Oh, actually, it looks like if I simply mark the `left` and `right` parameters of the operator as `in` (and construct a new return object instead of modifying `left`) then it works great, without having to make the structs readonly! Both the `MyVector` and `MyVectorSimd` versions then give essentially identical performance to `System.Numerics.Vector4`. Thanks @Christopher for pointing me in the right dirtection!

Comment: Curiously, this does *not* seem to work for `System.Numerics.Vector2`. I have been unable to create a custom 2-element float vector that comes close to the performance of `System.Numerics.Vector2`, even if I make the struct readonly. In fact, `System.Numerics.Vector2` seems to be slower per-vector when doing the same simple addition test than `System.Numerics.Vector4`.

Comment: Structs should always be readonly. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/441309/why-are-mutable-structs-evil

Comment: @JamesFaix Okay, but that's not really relevant to the problem at hand. Making my structs readonly was not necessary to improve Vector4 performance, and does nothing to improve Vector2/3 performance.

Comment: It is a data integrity concern with your struct.

Comment: Well then it's also a concern with `System.Numerics.Vector2/3/4`, which is also non-readonly, and my intent is for my custom Vector2/3/4 to be a drop-in replacement for `System.Numerics.Vector2/3/4`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Christopher in the comments to my original question, I was able to figure out that simply adding the `in` keyword to the `left` and `right` operator parameters (and rewriting them to create a new return value instead of modifying the `left` value) is enough to trigger the optimizations. This updated code gives essentially identical performance for all three vector variants:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Numerics;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

class Program
{
    private const int ARR_LENGTH = 1000;
    private const int OUTER_LOOP = 1000000;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        TestVector4();
        TestMyVector();
        TestMyVectorSimd();
    }

    static void TestVector4()
    {
        Vector4[] arr = new Vector4[ARR_LENGTH];
        for(int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
            arr[i] = new Vector4(i, i, i, i);

        Stopwatch sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        Vector4 total = default;
        for(int i = 0; i < OUTER_LOOP; i++)
        {
            total = default;
            for(int j = 0; j < ARR_LENGTH; j++)
                total += arr[j];
        }
        sw.Stop();

        Console.WriteLine($"System.Numerics.Vector4: {total}  ({sw.Elapsed})");
    }

    static void TestMyVector()
    {
        MyVector[] arr = new MyVector[ARR_LENGTH];
        for(int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
            arr[i] = new MyVector(i, i, i, i);

        Stopwatch sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        MyVector total = default;
        for(int i = 0; i < OUTER_LOOP; i++)
        {
            total = default;
            for(int j = 0; j < ARR_LENGTH; j++)
                total += arr[j];
        }
        sw.Stop();

        Console.WriteLine($"MyVector: {total}  ({sw.Elapsed})");
    }

    static void TestMyVectorSimd()
    {
        MyVectorSimd[] arr = new MyVectorSimd[ARR_LENGTH];
        for(int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
            arr[i] = new MyVectorSimd(i, i, i, i);

        Stopwatch sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        MyVectorSimd total = default;
        for(int i = 0; i < OUTER_LOOP; i++)
        {
            total = default;
            for(int j = 0; j < ARR_LENGTH; j++)
                total += arr[j];
        }
        sw.Stop();

        Console.WriteLine($"MyVectorSimd: {total}  ({sw.Elapsed})");
    }
}

struct MyVector
{
    public float X, Y, Z, W;

    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining | MethodImplOptions.AggressiveOptimization)]
    public MyVector(float x, float y, float z, float w)
    {
        X = x;
        Y = y;
        Z = z;
        W = w;
    }

    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining | MethodImplOptions.AggressiveOptimization)]
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"<{X}, {Y}, {Z}, {W}>";
    }

    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining | MethodImplOptions.AggressiveOptimization)]
    public static MyVector operator +(in MyVector left, in MyVector right)
    {
        return new MyVector(left.X + right.X, left.Y + right.Y, left.Z + right.Z, left.W + right.W);
    }
}

struct MyVectorSimd
{
    public Vector4 V;

    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining | MethodImplOptions.AggressiveOptimization)]
    public MyVectorSimd(float x, float y, float z, float w)
        : this()
    {
        V = new Vector4(x, y, z, w);
    }

    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining | MethodImplOptions.AggressiveOptimization)]
    public MyVectorSimd(Vector4 v)
        : this()
    {
        V = v;
    }

    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining | MethodImplOptions.AggressiveOptimization)]
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return V.ToString();
    }

    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining | MethodImplOptions.AggressiveOptimization)]
    public static MyVectorSimd operator +(in MyVectorSimd left, in MyVectorSimd right)
    {
        return new MyVectorSimd(left.V + right.V);
    }
}
```

Results:

```
System.Numerics.Vector4: <499500, 499500, 499500, 499500>  (00:00:00.9987530)
MyVector: <499500, 499500, 499500, 499500>  (00:00:01.0064586)
MyVectorSimd: <499500, 499500, 499500, 499500>  (00:00:00.9739642)
```

**EDIT:** This works for Vector4 but for whatever reason doesn't work for Vector2 or Vector3. Still looking for an answer as to how to create a custom Vector2 or Vector3 that gives similar performance to those in System.Numerics.

Comment: FYI, this is a speed question. And for those, the Speed Rant applies: https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/